# How to pass Schema name or Table name as a parameter into an Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pass table name as a parameter in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690038/is-it-possible-to-pass-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-oracle)

I would like to set up an Oracle query where I can externally pass a the Schema or Table name as a variable. For instance:

```
Select *
FROM &TableName a, &TableName2 b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
```

However above does not work. Any feedback would be appreciated. 
 Thank you.

Comment: What tool/ language are you trying to use?  Are you trying to use SQL*Plus substitution variables?  If the names of the tables are not known at compile time, then you'd be in a position where you would have to use dynamic SQL where you created a string that contains the SQL statement and execute that.  Depending on exactly what your requirements are, that can be relatively complex or relatively easy.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690038/is-it-possible-to-pass-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-oracle?rq=1