# Oracle dynamic PL/SQL. I cant get it to work

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

So here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_USER
(
  updateColumn IN USERS.column_name%type,
  changeStr IN VARCHAR2,
  unID IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'UPDATE
      users
    SET :1 = :2
    WHERE
      uniqueID = :3'
  USING updateColumn, changeStr, unID; 
END;
/
```

I've searched for other answers on this and as far as I can tell this should work. However I get the error:
    'Error(3,25): PLS-00302: component 'COLUMN_NAME' must be declared'

Thanks.

Comment: Does your `USERS` table actually have a column called `column_name`? It seems not from what you're trying to do. You probably need to declare `updateColumn` as `user_tab_columns.colmn_name%type`, or a simple `varchar2`. You can't dynamically set the column name in the update using a bind variable though.

Comment: @AlexPoole The answer in this is what I was aiming at: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690038/is-it-possible-to-pass-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message specifies line 3, character 25, which points to `column_name` in the declaration of the `updateColumn` parameter. It appears that you are trying to pass the column name to update as a parameter, but that means that at compile time the column isn't known, so its type can't be known. This also doesn't really make sense - if it's a `number` column then you'd be trying to pass the column name into a numeric parameter, which wouldn't work anyway. If you don't want to declare it as a simple `varchar2`, you could instead use `user_tab_columns.column_name%type`.

But you can't dynamically set the column name in the update statement using a bind variable. It would compile, but would get an `ORA-01747` on execution from the apparent name starting with a colon. You'd need to concatenate it, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_USER
(
  updateColumn IN user_tab_columns.column_name%type,
  changeStr IN VARCHAR2,
  unID IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'UPDATE
      users
    SET ' || updateColumn || ' = :1
    WHERE
      uniqueID = :2'
  USING changeStr, unID; 
END;
/
```

But you'd need to sanitise the column name to [avoid SQL injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BJECFFHD). APC's [answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690058/266304) mentions using the `DBMS_ASSERT` package, for example.

Comment: Thankyou for this Alex.
I did have the concatonation in before, however i removed becuase of this error at runtime: `ORA-00971: missing SET keyword`. The `user_tab_columns.column_name%type` appears to be an improvement however I am still getting that runtime error.

Comment: @TomStone - are you sure you have whitespace between the `SET` and the closing quote before the concatenation? Might be worth printing out the query as it will actually be executed to check.

Comment: Sorry that error has gone now and I am getting `ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
ORA-06512: at "THOMASSTONE.UPDATE_USER", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Comment: @TomStone - well, just guessing, but did you change the bind variable numbers back to `:1` and `:2`, and remove `updateColumn` from the `using` clause?