# Is there any way to use a PLSQL variable in 'FROM' clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi Is there any way to use a PL sql variable in from clause?
i am using below code but i am getting error in select statement that "Table Not Found"

```
declare 
--var varchar2(20);
cursor cur is
    select table_name from my_tables where table_name like 'RATED%';
    v_rows cur%rowtype;
--V_name varchar2(20);
begin
    open cur;
    loop
        fetch cur into v_rows;  
            exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
            select * from v_rows.table_name;  --here i am getting error.
   end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass table name as a parameter in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690038/is-it-possible-to-pass-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-oracle)

Comment: can you please let me know why you need to select statement? You cannot just write a select statement without execute immediate. Can you just share your problem what you want to implement

Comment: Yes i was stucked with execute immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You cannot use variables as table or schema names.
You'll have to use native dynamic SQL or DBMS_SQL for this.

Also, you cannot use a plain 'SELECT * from v_rows.table_name' in PL/SQL - you need an INTO clause (a "target" where you put the results of the SELECT).

Here's an example that should put you on the right track:

```
create table my_tables as select table_name as table_name from user_tables;

declare
  cursor cur is
    select table_name
      from my_tables
       where table_name like 'RATED%';
  v_rows cur%rowtype;
  v_cnt  pls_integer;
  v_SQL varchar2(4000);
begin
  open cur;
  loop
    fetch cur into v_rows;
    exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
    v_SQL := 'select count(*) from ' || v_rows.table_name;
    -- debug output
    dbms_output.put_line(v_SQL);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL INTO v_cnt;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_rows.table_name || ' : ' || v_cnt);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: now i am using  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from ' || c.table_name || ' minus select count(*) from wait.' || c.table_name
INTO v_cnt;
but getting error ' No data found', What could be the solution?

Comment: Try printing the SQL statement before you call EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, and run the SQL statement directly - this should give you an idea what went wrong (I've updated my answer).

Comment: @user2629100 - that is a new question and you should post it as such.  StackOverflow is a Q&A site not a forum.  Please respect the community by using the site properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql for such:

```
excute immediate 'select * from ' || v_rows.table_name;
```

Please look at the [description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm) of `execute immediate` and  `DBMS_SQL` to learn dynamic sql.

To get results from such queries you have to use explicit cursors (also explained in the description mentioned above).